# CSS Layout: Mix order of elements between items of two columns

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to achieve the following:

[image: Layout]

The height of elements is not fixed but based on content. The width of elements is a percentage of the layout space.

Is this possible with Flexbox or Grid?

Comment: are these fixed elements (sizes) and orders? Because then gridbox's [grid-template-areas](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#aa-grid-template-areas) might be exactly what you need.

Comment: @Plagiatus there is no fixed height involved anywhere in the layout. The width is always a percentage of the layout space.

Comment: Essentially not possible with flexbox or Css-grid unless you have two containers. You can do things afterwards but you need to start with two containers

Comment: I agree - I don't think this is possible with CSS only. JS sure, but CSS only unfortunately not. Unless you're willing to double one of the rows and show or hide the elements depending on screen size.

Comment: It is barely possible provided there are two column containers. You can use display contents to unwrap them for mobile.

Comment: @Paulie_D that would however not mix their order, would it? unless you use the `order` attribute to number them respectively. Yeah, that could work I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments and discussion with @Paulie_D, here is a css only solution that works.

It makes use of the fact that you can use `display: contents` to unwrap the items logically when the screen is small, as well as the fact that you can set the place in the order of the element through `order: X` (both in css).

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px){
  .inner {
    display: contents;
  }
  .outer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div id="a1" style="order:1"> A1
    </div>
    <div id="a2" style="order:4"> A2
    </div>
    <div id="a3" style="order:5"> A3
    </div>
    <div id="a4" style="order:7"> A4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div id="b1" style="order:2"> B1
    </div>
    <div id="b2" style="order:3"> B2
    </div>
    <div id="b3" style="order:6"> B3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```